# A question about nilpotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, nilpotence

Assume $A,B$ are two $2\times2$ nilpotent matrices with $AB=BA$, and the entries of $A$ and $B$ are from a field $F$. How to show there is a nonzero-vector $v$ from $F^2$ s.t. $Av=Bv=0$

Comment: Are you sure you want to multiply $k$ to the _right_ by $A$ and tie the _left_ by $B$; the first requires it to be viewed as a row matrix, and the second as a column matrix (so there is an implicit transposition going on, which seems weird)?

Comment: Also you want to exclude the zero vector for $k$, probably (otherwise it is to easy). [You might also consider calling the vector $v$ rather than $k$, which is usually used to denote integers.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**This part is no longer relevant, in light of the correction to the question.** Interpreting $vA$ as $v^T A$, the result is not true.  For example, take $F= \mathbb{C}$ and

$$A=B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

If $v=(x, y)$ then $Bv=0$ forces $y=0$ whilst $v^T A=0$ forces $x=0$.]

So I'll assume you mean $Av$, and hence that we want a non-zero $v \in \ker A \cap \ker B$.  This can be deduced from the following two facts:

1. A nilpotent matrix has non-trivial kernel, otherwise it would be invertible and hence not nilpotent.
2. Commuting matrices act on each other's eigenspaces.  So if $V \subset F^2$ is an eigenspace of $A$ then for all $v \in V$ we have $Bv \in V$.

Applying 1 to $A$ we see that $\ker A$ is non-trivial.  Now applying 2 (with $V$ the $0$-eigenspace, i.e. kernel, of $A$) we see that $B_{\ker A}$ is a nilpotent matrix acting on $\ker A$.  Applying $1$ again we see that $\ker B|_{\ker A}$ is non-trivial, so there exists non-zero $v \in \ker B_{\ker A} = \ker A \cap \ker B$.

Comment: Sorry, I think I made a mistake, and I have fixed it should be Av=Bv=0.

Comment: Note that this proof works for arbitrary size commuting nilpotent matrices, +1. For the $2\times2$ case one could show, if one excludes the boring case where $A$ or $B$ is zero, that the $0$-eigenspaces must even coincide; indeed in this case commuting nilpotent matrices must be linearly dependent (scalar multiples of one another).

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is nilpotent, hence roots of its characteristic polynomial are $0,0$, and the Characteristic polynomial of $A$ will be $x^2$. By Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $A^2=0$. Similarly $B^2=0$.

If one of $A$ and $B$ is zero matrix (operator on $F^2$) then your conclusion is obvious.

Assume that $A\neq 0\neq B$.

Let $W=\langle w\rangle$ be an eigenspace of $A$ with eigenvalue $0$. (Note that $A$ vanishes on $W$ and it cannot vanish out side $W$, otherwise, if $Av=0$ for some $v\in F^2-W$, then $A$ vanishes on $\langle w,v\rangle=F^2$ i.e. $A=0$).

We show that $W$ is also an eigenspace of $B$ with eigenvalue $0$.

Now $Aw=0$. Hence $BAw=0$, i.e. $ABw=0$.

- If $Bw=0$ then $w$ is a required vector.
- If $Bw\neq 0$, then $ABw=0$ implies that $Bw$ is an eigen-vector of $A$ with eigen-value $0$; it should be in $\langle w\rangle$, say $Bw=\alpha w$. Apply $B$ again, $BBw=B^2w=0w=0$. $A$ also vanishesh on $Bw$, since $\langle Bw\rangle=\langle \alpha w\rangle=\langle w\rangle=$ eigen-space of $A$ (with eigen-value $0$).

Hence $k=Bw$ is required vector.

(The argument above is independent of basis, although your question is written with a specific basis (standard basis).)